# Corona simple eventListener

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

I can't figure out why my button won't change appearance when pressed, can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with  the following snippet. I am using Corona SDK

This is my complete main.lua, if i remove the event listener the buttonswap works.

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar);

local textObj = display.newRetinaText("Click and see what happens!", 40, 40, nil, 0)
textObj:setTextColor(255,0,0);

local widget = require "widget";

local button = widget.newButton{
    default = "Button.png",
    over = "ButtonClicked.png",
    onPress = button.touch;
      }

button.x = display.contentCenterX;
button.y = display.contentCenterY+200;

local function touch(e)
if(e.phase == "began")then
        textObj.text = "Clicked!";
        textObj:setTextColor(255,255,255);
elseif(e.phase == "ended") then
        textObj.text = "Released!";
        textObj:setTextColor(255,0,0);
    end
end
```

Now i can only see the text, and not the button!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and button is changing when clicked. The only reason I can come up with is that the ButtonClicked.png is missing. Check the console (window named Corona Simulator Output) for any errors.

Also, cover the bases:
Make sure you are running the same main.lua you are editing.

After edit:

I believe you are overriding default button behaviour with

```
button:addEventListener("touch", button);
```

Try using constructor parameter **onPress**.

```
local button = widget.newButton{
    default = "Button.png",
    over = "ButtonClicked.png",
    onPress = touch
}
```

Comment: It is the right main.lua, and the ButtonClicked is in the same folder as that main file... strange

Comment: does the eventlistener override my button definition ? in that case how would i solve it ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, given that i am a complete rookie at corona i will edit my code once more. It still wont work

Comment: Edited once again. I should have at least some errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it! Here's how i did it.

```
local button = widget.newButton{
default = "Button.png",
over = "ButtonClicked.png",

}
button.x = display.contentCenterX;
button.y = display.contentCenterY+200;


function button:tap( e )
-- Do what you want to do when event occurs
end

button:addEventListener( "tap", button );
```